# jQuery get val of a link?

Tags: jquery

I just trying to get the anchor text of a link.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alerT($(this).val());
});

<a href="#">test</a>
```

I have the above code, but for some reason it always returns empty.

Am i missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `.text()`. `.val()` works for input and textarea only.

Answer (score 1):

Change `val()` to `text()`. You should also make that `T` lowercase on `alerT`, but I think that might just be a typo. You also need to make sure that your `<a>` comes before your script or your script is in a document ready. One more thing is that if your `href` is anything not begining with a hash, or you want to prevent the page from scrolling on click you can return false from your click event:

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

The `text` method gets any text nodes within the specified element (in this case, the anchor text). In this case `html()` would work as well, but that also gets any child elements, not just text.

The `val` method is used for things like `input` elements, which have a `value` attribute. For example:

```
$("input#someId").change(function() {
   alert($(this).val());
});
```

That will alert the value entered into the input element.